# Throttle file uploads using Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to throttle only file uploads (not downloads) using Apache 2 on a per-directory basis?

I've tried using mod_bw and looked at mod_throttle, but neither seem to support upload throttling, only downloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite **difficult** to **throttle uploads**, since you are **not at the source** of the sending.

The only thing you can do is to **temper TCP ACKs** (by delaying them).

I don't know a reliable way to do it at the application level, except of not reading the socket anymore. A quite general way would be to **do it at the OS level**.

A solution at apache's level would be something like [bwshare](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html). If you want to avoid DOS, you can just send 503 as quoted in media wiki's [Request Throttling](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Request_throttling) page.

Comment: how might one go about doing it at the OS level?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your question